# Subset Data with the assign Function in R

Tags: r, subset, assign

I'm new to programming in R (or at all), and I've been stuck on a problem for a few days. Apologies if this question already exists in some form, but I've looked as best I can and can't find anything.

I have multiple datasets called pop1, pop2, pop3, etc. and I'm trying to assign a value of zero to a specified subset of them from within a for loop. Through trial and error, I've found that the code:

```
subset(get(paste("pop", 1, sep = "")), ind == 46, select = -ind)
```

returns the subset I'm looking for, but when I try:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(subset(get(paste("pop", i, sep = "")), ind == 46, select = -ind), 0)
}
```

I get the error message:

```
#Error in assign(subset(get(paste("pop", i, sep = "")), ind == 46, select = -ind),  : 
  #invalid first argument
```

It seems to me that the assign function won't take subsets as its first argument, since none of the following work either:

```
assign(pop1[46, -1], 0)
assign(pop1$trait1, 0)
assign(subset(pop1, ind == 46), 0)
```

Is there a way I can make this work? Thanks very much, and let me know if more information would be helpful.

Comment: Put all pops into a list object, then use lapply to avoid "get assign" problems.

Comment: One trick is to create a command string and use the `eval(parse(text=yourtext))`. `a <- matrix(1:6,3,2)` and then `eval(parse(text=sprintf("%s[%d,%d] <- 0", "a",1,1)))`. It's hard to type R codes on a smart phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments its easier to do these kind of task via a list.

You can keep all your data sets in a list. Then using regular sub-setting, you can do regular assignments.

```
df1=data.frame(a=1:10,b=c(1,2))
df2=data.frame(a=1:10,b=c(1,2))
l=list(df1,df2)
lapply(l, function(x) { x[which(x[,2]==1),2]=999; return(x)})
```

If you like to do this in a loop then one can use parse along with eval.

```
for(i in 1:2){
    txt=paste('df',i,'[df',i,'[,2]==1,2]','=999', sep = "")
    eval(parse(text = txt))
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I couldn't get lapply to work for what I needed because I had a lot of other stuff going on in the for loop that I couldn't get to work inside lapply (I'm not saying this wasn't possible, but I wasn't able to), but I've got the code to work for my original purpose now by making a function to subset the data, so thanks very much!

Comment: I understand you concern, So here is the for loop that you can work with.